# Accessing session variable inside css file laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have a css file name **style-usercolors.css.php** for dynamic css color in my laravel app. Inside the file I can declare variable and use it, but can't access the session variable.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");

$primaryColor = session()->has('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS') ? session()->get('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS')['style_settings']['primary_color'] : '#F18805';
$secondaryColor = session()->has('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS') ? session()->get('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS')['style_settings']['secondary_color'] : '#20576B';
$offwhite = '#f6f6f6';
```

Comment: How you try to access session variable?

Comment: did you add session_start() at the beginning of the file?

Comment: $primaryColor = session()->has('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS') ? session()->get('ORGANISATION_SETTINGS')['style_settings']['primary_color'] : '#F18805'; @Galstyan

Comment: try session(''ORGANISATION_SETTINGS'')

Comment: I removed the `php` tag from code and minimized tabbing and made slight improvements to the English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'v created a blade file and there I write css along with session variable then include blade file into layout header section. And this process solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a defined route to access the session in Laravel. When you define routes in **web.php**, the **StartSession** Middleware is enabled by default. That starts the Laravel session.

These middlewares are defined in App\Http\Kernel.php, in the web section.

In other words, to use the session, you need to create a specific route for your css file, add: `header("Content-Type: text/css");` to it and require your css there.

Finally, in your main view, you have to create a link to that page:

`<link href="http://example.com/link-to-your-css-page/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

( Notice how we don't have a file extension at the end of the href attribute )

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to create route for a css file?